# CSS mobile view off screen position issue

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with my text image and footer position. Whenever it is in mobile view the text stacks one and other with the images and the design doesn't look how I want it. I have tried using `@media screen and (max-width: 480px)` but I could not get it working.
I want the mobile view to fit in the screen and not go out of the screen.
Desire how I want it to look like almost the desktop version is fine is just that the mobile version is not working properly:

Mobile view:

[image]
Desktop view:

[image]

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
}
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 25%;
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
 position: fixed;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
}
li a {
 display: block;
 color: #000;
 padding: 8px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
li a.active {
 background-color: #4CAF50;
 color: white;
}
li a:hover:not(.active) {
 background-color: #555;
 color: white;
}
.container {
 margin-left: 25%;
 padding: 1px 16px;
 height: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 ul {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
 }
 .container {
  /* margin: 0 auto; is a great trick for centering */
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1px 16px;
  height: 1000px;
 }
 /* remove the set width on your items */
 div.item {
  width: initial;
 }

}
div.item {
 vertical-align: top;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 width: 520px;
}
.blog {
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 background-color: grey;
}
.caption {
 display: block;
}
img {
 display: block;
}
img.wrap {
 max-width: 70%;
 margin: 30px 0px;
}
img.align-right {
 float: right;
 margin-left: 30px;
}
div.article-container {
 padding: 5px;
}
.clearfix:after {
 content: "";
 display: table;
 clear: both;
}
.footer {
 position: fixed;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 padding: 1rem;
 background-color: #efefef;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>web</title>
 <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li><img alt="htmll logo" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png"></li>
   <li>
    <a class="active" href="#home">Länk 1</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#news">Länk 2</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#contact">Länk 3</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#about">Länk 4</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 <div class="container">
  <h1>Innehåll</h1>
  <div class="item">
   <img alt="htmll logo" class="blog" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png"> <span class="caption">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <img alt="htmll logo" class="blog" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png"> <span class="caption">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <img alt="htmll logo" class="blog" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png"> <span class="caption">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</span>
  </div>
 </div>
 <hr>
  <div class="container">
 <div class="article-container clearfix">
  <img class="wrap align-right" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png" alt="html logo">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
 </div>
</div>
 <div class="footer">
  This footer will always be positioned at the bottom of the page, but <strong>not fixed</strong>.
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what exactly is not "how you wanted"? Not very clear.

Comment: @WilomGfx I want it to be responsive and fit in the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the .item class to max-width:

```
max-width: 520px;
```

This will keep the text from staying at 520px and going over the side.

Also, on that media query of 480px for the .container class, remove the:

```
height: 1000px;
```

to keep the text from jumbling after the width change.